# Updating Angular HotTowel v2.3.3 to latest Angular packages in VS2015 kills routing

Tags: angularjs, hottowel

**background**:
I'm just getting started with AngularJS and I'm using HotTowel as a starting point.
I've actually done a fair amount of work with HotTowel and have several features built for an application I'm doing. What led me to this problem is trying to get ui-grid in to my application. It blows up. Looking at HotTowel it seems to have been a while since it was last update, but the Angular stuff (and other libraries) are full steam ahead. When I update all of the Angular packages HotTowel's navigation stuff stops working. I'm going to start chasing it down, but I thought I might ask if somebody else has already fixed this issue to save myself some time.

**Reproduction**:
I'm using VisualStudio2015. My project is an ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework) w/ just MVC added.
For the reproduction of the issue I used the above in a new solution. I then went to manage NuGet packages and update everything to latest, there should be 10 updates. This requires a restart of Visual Studio.
Once I'm back in I return to my solution and bring up Manage NuGet pakages again. This time I go to Browse and find HotTowel. This brings up a short list. I select HotTowl.Angular by John Papa (~73.6K downloads, version v2.3.3) and install it. Allow it to overwrite the favorite icon.

After NuGet finishes go to the solution explorer, find Index.HTML, right click on it and select "set as start page". Now, open Index.html and change line 51 to say "" and save it.
Now do a rebuild all and then run the application using Google Chrome (issue will occur with any browser). Everything works great. You can switch between dashboard and admin.

Stop the application and return to manage nuget package. select the update tab and update all of the packages. You'll be asked about overwriting some map files, go ahead and do it.

Do another rebuild all and then run the application.
The dashboard will come up as before, click on admin. You will see dashboard fade out and then fade back in. This is the issue. the routes appear to be broken.

At this point there is nothing custom in the solution. We have just updated all of the packages to their latest releases. HotTowel, however seems to have a gone stale.

Being new to Angular, and HotTowel. I'm not sure where to start debugging this.
At a guess the issue is with how the code in config.route.js sets up the routes.

Can somebody please give me some hints on how to fix this?

TIA

Comment: You may want to refine your question by removing some of the waffle and adding some reproducible code as an example. Opening the question to a huge wall of text isn't going to attract a lot of attention.

Comment: The "wall of text" is the reproduction.  There isnt any coding involved, just updating the packages HotTowel depends on breaks things for you.

Comment: It appears that something changed in how angular does routing.  Using other people's samples that refer to Angular-1.0.7 and changing the reference to 1.6.2 makes their sample stop working (http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/).

Comment: Would love an explanation.  As explained above - the addition of the '!' to the nav URL after the sharp '#' fixes the issue.  No idea what happened between the earlier version of Angular and the latest.